# How do I get around a version conflict in pip itself?

Tags: python, pip

So I have both python 2.7 and 3.6 installed, with symbolic links for pip, pip2, and pip3:

```
> ll /usr/bin/pip*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  16 Dec  4 16:42 /usr/bin/pip -> /usr/bin/pip-3.6
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  16 Dec  4 14:39 /usr/bin/pip2 -> /usr/bin/pip-2.7
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 370 Apr 25  2018 /usr/bin/pip-2.7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  16 Dec  4 14:39 /usr/bin/pip3 -> /usr/bin/pip-3.6
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 370 Apr 25  2018 /usr/bin/pip-3.6
```

But when I try to get the version number for pip-3.6, it fails:

```
> pip --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 658, in _build_master
    ws.require(__requires__)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 972, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 863, in resolve
    raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req)
pkg_resources.VersionConflict: (pip 19.3.1 (/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages), Requirement.parse('pip==9.0.3'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 6, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3049, in <module>
    @_call_aside
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3033, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3062, in _initialize_master_working_set
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 660, in _build_master
    return cls._build_from_requirements(__requires__)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 673, in _build_from_requirements
    dists = ws.resolve(reqs, Environment())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 858, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'pip==9.0.3' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

Note that it correctly recognizes the 3.6 version of pip is 19.3.1 (the current version), but it's requiring 9.0.3, which is the 2.7 version:

```
> pip2 --version
pip 9.0.3 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)
```

Any attempt to use the 3.6 version of pip (e.g., `/usr/bin/pip-3.6 install --upgrade pip`) fails.

I'd love to get rid of one of the python versions, but I'm trying to `pip install ansible`, and it requires the latest version of pip, and I have to support 2 & 3 (and yes, I know 2 is EOL in January).

I will appreciate all suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: What does `python3 -m pip --version` return?

Comment: Pipenv is recommended for this kind of issues, https://pypi.org/project/pipenv/

Comment: @JohnAnderson: `python3 -m pip --version` returns `pip 19.3.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)`

Comment: So, whenever you want to use `pip3`, just use `python3 -m pip`.

Comment: Perhaps you can update pip2 to 19.3.1 with `sudo -H python2 -m pip install --upgrade pip`.

Comment: @JohnAnderson Thank you! Excellent suggestions!